# Mac using Word 2011

Tags: images, templates, microsoft-word-2011

I have to create a Word template, with a full size (the size of the document setup) image in the background that will be static. The problem I have is how to get the image in the background and have it remain the same size and in the same position when I open a new doc based on the template. I placed the picture using Fill/Picture, upload from computer, and it looks great. Then saved the file as a template. When I open it again, the background(fill) image has been scaled to about 200-300%, and I have not been able to determine why.

I appreciate any solution you can offer.

Thank you!